# Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am tring to invote internal media player of android from my activity.
Seems there is some problem in menifest file .

Please look into this issue .

08-04 18:08:47.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1386): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///sdcard/audiodata.wav }

Answer (score 1):

This is for internal audio player:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File("/sdcard/test0.mp3");   
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), MIME_AUDIO);  
_context.startActivity(intent);
```